# Download a file from HTML Page Using Spring

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I want to download a file from from the front end. The file is generated on `TestFlow.generateReport`

My runs until the end but it doesn't download anything. What am I missing here??

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/flow/generate-report" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void generateFlowReport(@RequestParam("flowName") String flowName, HttpServletResponse response) {
    InputStream resource = TestFlow.generateReport(flowName);
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=report-" + flowName + ".xlsx");
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(resource,response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
        resource.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this generate-report? value = "/flow/generate-report"

Comment: ajax post. It just sends the name of the flow. The generateReport method creates an excel and passes the inputstream to the controller.

Comment: have you tried different content types?
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream"); for example?

Comment: @juju didnt work

Comment: what does your ajax post look like?

Comment: for excel I've been using these content type headers;
xls - "application/vnd.ms-excel", xlsx - "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet". I generally create a byte [] with files and do: try (OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream()) 
            {
                outStream.write(bytes);
                outStream.flush();
            }

Comment: Shouldn't you have a value like (value = '/flow/{file_name}" , and the @RequestParam, why don'y you use @PathVariable("file_name") String fileName,

Comment: Also isn't the 'Spring' way to set content type like this? @RequestMapping(value = "/flow/generate-report", produces = "application/force-download", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Answer (score 0):

The original AJAX request can not handle file download request.
You must create a virtual form. [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post/23797348). And there are lots of jQuery plugin help you to do this.

And since its a download request, your controller method should not use `@ResponseBody`, take over the response all by yourself, close it after writing the content.